# Jetty RequestLog - issue reading request body

Tags: java, logging, jetty, httprequest

I use Jetty and I want to log requests' parameters and body.

Adding AccessLogger to handlers:

```
    ServletContextHandler servletContextHandler = new ServletContextHandler();
    ...

    RequestLogHandler requestLogHandler = new RequestLogHandler();
    requestLogHandler.setRequestLog(new AccessLogger());

    HandlerCollection handlers = new HandlerCollection();
    handlers.setHandlers(new Handler[]{
            servletContextHandler,
            requestLogHandler
    });
```

AccessLogger implements RequstLog interface:

```
@Override
public void log(Request request, Response response) {
    request.getReader();
}
```

The issue is that when I try to run `request.getReader()` it says `IllegalStateException: STREAMED`. I assume that's because previous handler has already read all the data. But how can I log it the way I need then?

Answer (score 0):

Standard Servlet behavior.

If your Servlet reads the Request body (via either `getInputStream()` or `getReader()`) then you have read it, it cannot be read again.

The technique used, `getReader()` or `getInputStream()` is how that body content was presented, and cannot be changed.

- If you used `getReader()`, then `getInputStream()` cannot be used later.
- If you used `getInputStream()` then `getReader()` cannot be used later.

See the Javadoc for [`getReader()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getReader--) and [`getInputStream()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getInputStream--) for more details.

Comment: Yes, that's what I assumed. But what's the workaround for this case? If there can be multiple handlers they all should be able to read from request, right?

Comment: Nope, that's not supported by the servlet spec.  If you have that need, then you'll have to read and cache the content somewhere (would recommend on disk), and then each subsequent servlet would need to access this cached version (not via the servlet api).   You could come up with something complex that overrides/wraps the HttpServletRequest, but that's less viable of an option since Servlet 3.1 and Async I/O was added to the spec.